# Como puedo utilizar el comando (cd ..) en python

Tags: python

He hecho un programa en python cliente-servidor pero no puedo utilizar el comando en cd en modo shell que son los comandos que utilizo para msdos. Me han dicho con subprocesos se puede hacer he utilizado esto:

```
x = input("introduce el comando: ")
subprocess.call([x, ''], shell=True)
subprocess.call('cd ..', shell=True)
```

Con un bucle while repito las secuencias y voy introduciendo el comando que yo quiera. pero el cd nunca me lo hace.

usar una funcion que simule el comando cd ..

## to go back in directory (this will give effect of cd..)

```
def back():
    path=os.getcwd()
    print path
    s=path.split('\\')
    length=len(s)
    x=0

    while x<(length-1):
        if x==0:
            back_path=s[x]+"\\"
        else:
            back_path=back_path+s[x]+"\\"
        x+=1

    os.chdir(back_path)
```

como puedo implementar en mi programa

python el peor lenguaje que he visto no se puede ni usar el cd .. .....

Answer (score 2):

El probelma es que `subprocess.call` inicia un nuevo proceso, y es este proceso el que cambia de directorio y no el proceso de tu script.

Para cambiar de directorio el proceso actual usa [`os.chdir`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html):

```
os.chdir("..")
```

Comment: si cuando arranque consola y introduzca el input que tengo que introducir? esque no quiero que me lo haga desde el script quiero introducirlo yo manualmente

Comment: es que es otro proceso el que cambia de directorio. Si quieres puedes usar `cwd ..`  o en su lugar parsear la entrada y si comienza con  `cd ` ejecutas `os.chdir`...

Comment: introduce el comando: 'os.chdir(..)'
'os.chdir' n'est pas reconnu en tant que commande interne
ou externe, un programme exécutable ou un fichier de commandes. No me deja cwd tampoco

Comment: hola mira a ver si con la funcion que puse podria conseguir algo

Answer (score 0):

Creo que tienes que importar la librería `os`: `import os`
Y seguido tienes que llamar a la función `os.system` que es la que ejecuta el comando, entonces quedaría así: `os.system("cd ..")`

Comment: no lo reconoce introduce el comando: "cd .."
'"cd .."' n'est pas reconnu en tant que commande interne
ou externe, un programme exécutable ou un fichier de commandes.
introduce el comando:

Comment: prueba con `os.system('chdir ..')`

Comment: no funciona tampoco mm es imposible usar cd pero he visto en videos que le utilizan no me funciono chdir ..

Comment: hola mira a ver si con la funcion que puse podria conseguir algo

Answer (score -1):

importando la librería os

```
os.system(“el codigo en bash a ejecutar”)
```

en tu caso `(“ cd..”)`

Hay un ligero problema y es que si pretendes ejecutar esto en un python instalado en Geany o algún framework en Windows, esta ejecución no va a ser posible, a menos que este previamente añadido lo necesario para tener shell.

Pycharm es my cómodo y fácil de configurar

Suerte!